# Python Selenium send_keys ~ How to send advanced Unicode Characters

Tags: python, selenium, special-characters

in order to write a test case that should test if a string input field really survives **all** possible inputs, I have compiled an "Omega Death String" containing a character from every current Unicode block. Here it is:

```
␡ÆĦǣʨ˧͚ΔѨ֍ࢥޛچضغ߷ࠇउगऴ৳ਸ਼ષନஹౙಯ൷ෂท໖༺ဪჭᆅቘᎆᎹᐇᚙᛤᜇᜰᝇᝧ៘ᢆᣢᢆᢆᡆᤗᥘᦜ᧻ᨋᩗ᪶ᬑᮼᯥᰒᱫᲇ᳄᳷ᵹᶋ᷼ỸὮ※ₘ₹⃟™ↈ↹∰⌦␥⑆⓭╃▙◍♅❦⟗⟹⡕⥇⧉⩷⭖Ⱗⱷ⳧ⴥⵥⶻⷵ⸾⻭⽧⿷〶きラ鏡狐ㄦㅶ㆗ㆧ㇡ㇺ㈿㍇㑴䷺亘ꁚ꓂ꓩꔫꚖꚼ꜕Ꝧꠚ꠷ꡪꢸꣶꤥꥅꥺ꧄ꧨꩆꩶ꫞ꫩꬤꭔꮚ꯹걗ퟶ珞ﬦﮖ︌︗︩︾﹠ﻉﾚ
```

I initially tried sending the Omega Death String via `send_keys`, but that resulted in a `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: missing command parameters`.

I have also already tried sending it via JavaScript using `execute_script`, as well as attempted to send a unicode encoded version of that string, but neither of that worked.

For now, I think I'll just prune the Omega Death String to contain only characters from the basic multilingual plane, but if anyone figures out a way to reliably enter it using Selenium for Python, I'd be highly interested.

Comment: Have you tried finding the UNICODE codes for these characters? e.g. `U+0041` for 'A' and so on. Once you do that, you should be able to send them all. See any list such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), etc.

Comment: @JeffC: Yup, that is what I meant when I said I attempted to send a unicode encoded version of that string. That also caused a `missing command parameters` Exception

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the problem in a Linux environment that is running Chrome as the default user:

```
def paste(str):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    p = Popen(['xsel', '-bi'], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(input=str)

paste(description)
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,"v")
```

If you don't have the program xsel, you could install it with something like `sudo yum install xsel`.

This doesn't work if you are running Chrome as a non-default user in an attempt to remember cookies, etc. For the record, here is how you become a non-default user:

```
opts.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome/selenium")
opts.add_argument('headless')
opts.add_argument('no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```

The directory selenium in the above example is a copy of the Default directory that is also in that directory.

So in my case, I developed some code that checks the text that I wish to post and run the script as the default user if I have non BMP text. (I prefer to run as a non-default user so I am not logging into sites like crazy.)

Comment: This almost works with Firefox and geckodriver. The first paste is correct, but after that it will always paste the same string even if `xsel` is called again.